# argparse position of positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Instead of this:

`usage: installer.py [-h] [-v] dir`

I would like to have this:

`usage: installer.py dir [-h] [-v]`

Is there a way of specifying the position of positional arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a positional argument, this argument can be consumed in either way, so you still can have

`installer.py dir [-h] [-v]`

And dir would be consumed, this is very similar to the example in the ArgParse documentation:
http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#example

Answer (score 0):

From the argparse Documentation

*By default, ArgumentParser calculates the usage message from the arguments it contains:*

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo [FOO]] bar [bar ...]
```

*The default message can be overridden with the usage= keyword argument:*

*>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG', usage='%(prog)s [options]')*

```
usage: PROG [options]
```